# Самое первое событие в приложении

Tags: c#, wpf, .net

Какое событие срабатывает раньше всего в WPF? Нужно чтобы при запуске программы проверялись настройки и открывалось нужное окно в зависимости от них. Но если написать код в `Window.Loaded`, то окно появляется до чтения настроек и приложение создаёт два окна, одно из которых моментально закрывается. Соответственно это событие не подходит.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Открываете App.xaml и убираете установку StartupUri:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfTest.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

</Application>
```

Затем, открываете App.xaml.cs и добавляете туда:

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnStartup(e);
    // Здесь код, который должен выполниться перед показом окна
    new MainWindow().Show();
}
```

Comment: Но visual studio ругается на `Properties.Settings.Default.Updated == 1`. Он не понимает что это и ругается на `System.Collections.IDictionary`

Comment: @OsidDev, это из-за того, что в классе `Application` уже есть свойство `Properties`, поэтому возникает неопределенность. Вам нужно просто добавить пространство имен, у меня это выглядит так: `WpfTest.Properties.Settings....`